# Find Available time in a day of one person

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am doing resource allocation for an event.

My event table for one resource is looks like this:

```
(Int)---(nvarchar(100)---(datetime)--(datetime)

EventId --- Event ---    StartTime ---              EndTime

1    /       test    /    2013-02-20 13:00:00   /   2013-02-20 15:00:00

2    /       test2   /     2013-02-20 09:30:00  /   2013-02-20 11:00:00

3    /       test3   /     2013-02-25 11:30:00  /   2013-02-25 14:30:00
```

Now I want to find the total availablity for this resource on one day.

Like on 20th Feb 2013 I want to remove the busy hours from this resource and want to show only available hours for new event.

I am using php and sql server 2008 r2.

It works fine with only one record of a single day. Right now I am using a foreach loop with calculation.

My Code is:

```
$id = 6;    
$cdata = $test->getResourceEvents($id);

$h = "";
$final= array();

foreach($cdata as $c)
   {

   $sh = $c['starttime']->Format('H'); // Starting hour
   $eh = $c['endtime']->Format('H'); // End hour

   $hh = $sh;
   $final = array();
   $sdate = $c['starttime']->Format('Y-m-d');
   $edate = $c['endtime']->Format('Y-m-d');
   if($edate == $sdate)
   {

   $dh = $eh-$sh; // Duration
       for($i=1;$i<=$dh;$i++)
       {
           $hh = $hh.",".($sh+$i); // Busy hours
       }    
   $busyhrs[$sdate] = explode(",",$hh);
       $final[$sdate] = $busyhrs;
   }
   else
   {
       echo "false";
   }
}

print_r($final);
```

and my result is :

```
Array
(
    [2013-02-20] => Array
        (
            [2013-02-20] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 9
                    [1] => 10
                    [2] => 11
                )

        )

    [2013-02-26] => Array
        (
            [2013-02-26] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 12
                    [2] => 13
                    [3] => 14
                )

        )

)
```

First two records have the same dates. but this only calculates 2nd row's hours. Not calculating first row's hours that is 13,14,15.

Can anyone please tell me how to match the dates and how to get total busy hours of one date?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? An array of time ranges? If you work back from the result you want, you will likely answer your own question.

Comment: yes, i want to an array of available time like available hours. I am making an array of busy hours and then removing that busy hours from the total working hours of the resource. but it works fine with only one record of one date. like for first 2 records it only counts 2nd records only. its not counting 10 to 13 hours as busy hours. I am wrong somewhere in logic. Please tell me how to do ?

Comment: If you want multiple records you probably need another array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I changed the process of making final array.
Thanks a lot to all for helping me.
I think its simple. 
Here is my code.

May be it will be helpful to someone.

```
        $id = 6;    
        $cdata = $test->getResourceEvents($id);

        $h = "";
        $final= array();

        foreach($cdata as $c)
        {
            $sh = $c['starttime']->Format('H'); // Starting hour

            $eh = $c['endtime']->Format('H'); // End hour


            $hh = $sh;
            $busyhrs = array();
            $sdate = $c['starttime']->Format('Y-m-d');
            $edate = $c['endtime']->Format('Y-m-d');
            if($edate == $sdate)
            {
                $dh = $eh-$sh; // Duration
                for($i=1;$i<=$dh;$i++)
                {
                    $hh = $hh.",".($sh+$i); // Busy hours
                }   

                if($final != array() || $final != NULL)
                {
                    foreach($final as $key=>$val)
                    {
                        if($key==$sdate)
                        {
                            $final[$key] = $val.",".$hh;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $final[$sdate] = $hh;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $final[$sdate] = $hh;
                }                           
            }
            else
            {
                echo "false";
            }
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this in Java.

I had a table with date ranges in it, and a date range that I had to insert into the lapses in coverage from the date ranges already present.

I essentially took the date range I'm interested in, and "subtract" all the existing date ranges. You'll find my subtract method in the code below.

Subtracting DateRange_B from DateRange_A results in DateRange_A being modified in place, and the method returning a new DateRange if DateRange_A got entirely split by DateRange_B.

There are of course other ways to solve this, such iterations in SQL SERVER, but I was already in a Java mindset and this solution just kinda happened.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2009, Ben Fortuna
 * (Modified by Alex Marunowski)
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 
 *  o Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 
 *  o Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 * notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 * documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 
 *  o Neither the name of Ben Fortuna nor the names of any other contributors
 * may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
 * without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author fortuna
 *
 */
public class DateRange implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7303846680559287286L;

    /**
     * A flag indicating whether to include the start of the period in test functions.
     */
    public static final int INCLUSIVE_START = 1;

    /**
     * A flag indicating whether to include the end of the period in test functions.
     */
    public static final int INCLUSIVE_END = 2;

    private Date rangeStart;

    private Date rangeEnd;

    /**
     * @param start the start of the range
     * @param end the end of the range
     */
    public DateRange(Date start, Date end) {
        if (start == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range start is null");
        }
        if (end == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range end is null");
        }
        if (end.before(start)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range start must be before range end");
        }
        this.rangeStart = start;
        this.rangeEnd = end;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rangeStart
     */
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return rangeStart;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rangeEnd
     */
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return rangeEnd;
    }

    public void setRangeStart(Date rangeStart) {
        if(rangeStart.after(getEndDate()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The start of a date range cannot be after its end!");

        this.rangeStart = rangeStart;
    }

    public void setRangeEnd(Date rangeEnd) {
        if(rangeStart.after(getEndDate()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The end of a date range cannot be after its start!");

        this.rangeEnd = rangeEnd;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the specified date occurs within this period (inclusive of
     * period start and end).
     * @param date a date to test for inclusion
     * @return true if the specified date occurs within the current period
     * 
     */
    public final boolean includes(final Date date) {
        return includes(date, INCLUSIVE_START | INCLUSIVE_END);
    }

    /**
     * Decides whether a date falls within this period.
     * @param date the date to be tested
     * @param inclusiveMask specifies whether period start and end are included
     * in the calculation
     * @return true if the date is in the period, false otherwise
     * @see Period#INCLUSIVE_START
     * @see Period#INCLUSIVE_END
     */
    public final boolean includes(final Date date, final int inclusiveMask) {
        boolean includes = true;
        if ((inclusiveMask & INCLUSIVE_START) > 0) {
            includes = includes && !rangeStart.after(date);
        }
        else {
            includes = includes && rangeStart.before(date);
        }
        if ((inclusiveMask & INCLUSIVE_END) > 0) {
            includes = includes && !rangeEnd.before(date);
        }
        else {
            includes = includes && rangeEnd.after(date);
        }
        return includes;
    }

    /**
     * Decides whether this period is completed before the given period starts.
     * 
     * @param range
     *            a period that may or may not start after this period ends
     * @return true if the specified period starts after this periods ends,
     *         otherwise false
     */
    public final boolean before(final DateRange range) {
        return (rangeEnd.before(range.getStartDate()));
    }

    /**
     * Decides whether this period starts after the given period ends.
     * 
     * @param range
     *            a period that may or may not end before this period starts
     * @return true if the specified period end before this periods starts,
     *         otherwise false
     */
    public final boolean after(final DateRange range) {
        return (rangeStart.after(range.getEndDate()));
    }

    /**
     * Decides whether this period intersects with another one.
     * 
     * @param range
     *            a possible intersecting period
     * @return true if the specified period intersects this one, false
     *         otherwise.
     */
    public final boolean intersects(final DateRange range) {
        boolean intersects = false;
        // Test for our start date in period
        // (Exclude if it is the end date of test range)
        if (range.includes(rangeStart) && !range.getEndDate().equals(rangeStart)) {
            intersects = true;
        }
        // Test for test range's start date in our range
        // (Exclude if it is the end date of our range)
        else if (includes(range.getStartDate())
                && !rangeEnd.equals(range.getStartDate())) {
            intersects = true;
        }
        return intersects;
    }

    /**
     * Decides whether these periods are serial without a gap.
     * @param range a period to test for adjacency
     * @return true if one period immediately follows the other, false otherwise
     */
    public final boolean adjacent(final DateRange range) {
        boolean adjacent = false;
        if (rangeStart.equals(range.getEndDate())) {
            adjacent = true;
        } else if (rangeEnd.equals(range.getStartDate())) {
            adjacent = true;
        }
        return adjacent;
    }

    /**
     * Decides whether the given period is completely contained within this one.
     * 
     * @param range
     *            the period that may be contained by this one
     * @return true if this period covers all the dates of the specified period,
     *         otherwise false
     */
    public final boolean contains(final DateRange range) {
        // Test for period's start and end dates in our range
        return (includes(range.getStartDate()) && includes(range.getEndDate()));
    }

    /**
     * Decides whether the given period is completely contained within this one, taking into consideration whether date ranges with matching start or end dates 
     * are counted as being contained
     * 
     * @param range
     *            the period that may be contained by this one
     * @param inclusiveMask
     *              if this is set to 0, the start and end dates cannot be the same date and have it be considered to be contained within this date range.
     *              this.contains(this, 1) returns true 
     *              this.contains(this, 0) returns false 
     * @return true if this period covers all the dates of the specified period,
     *         otherwise false
     */
    public final boolean contains(final DateRange range, int inclusiveMask) {
        // Test for period's start and end dates in our range
        return (includes(range.getStartDate(), inclusiveMask) && includes(range.getEndDate(), inclusiveMask));
    }


    /**
     * Exclude otherRange from the dates covered by this DateRange. Note: This will put the specified buffer around the range being subtracted from this date range. 
     * @param otherRange
     * @return an additional date range if subtracting otherRange from this DateRange results in a part of this objects DateRange being separated from the rest of the range. 
     * i.e. if this.includes(otherRange, 0), then there will be two remaining portions of this daterange.
     * If no dangling date range remains, then the method returns null.
     * @author Alex Marunowski. 2012.10.31
     */
    public DateRange subtract(DateRange otherRange, long buffer) throws DateRangeObliteratedException{

        Date bufferedStart = new Date(otherRange.getStartDate().getTime()-buffer);
        Date bufferedEnd= new Date(otherRange.getEndDate().getTime()+buffer);
        otherRange = new DateRange(bufferedStart, bufferedEnd);

        // If the other range is entirely after this range, nothing happens
        if(getEndDate().before(otherRange.getStartDate()))
            return null;

        // If the other range is entirely before this range, nothing happens
        if(getStartDate().after(otherRange.getEndDate()))
            return null;

        if(otherRange.contains(this))
            throw new DateRangeObliteratedException();

        DateRange separatedTimeInterval = null;
        if(this.contains(otherRange, 0)){

            // The trailing daterange is the time between the end date of the inner daterange, and the end date of the outer date range
            separatedTimeInterval = new DateRange(otherRange.getEndDate(), getEndDate());

            // This date range now ends at the start time of the inner date range
            this.setRangeEnd(otherRange.getStartDate());

            return separatedTimeInterval;
        }




        if(otherRange.getEndDate().before(getEndDate())){
            // This date range is now the time between the end of the otherRange plus the buffer time, and the end of this date range
            long newRangeStart = otherRange.getEndDate().getTime();
            this.setRangeStart(new Date(newRangeStart));
            return null;
        }

        if(otherRange.getStartDate().after(getStartDate())){
            // This date range is now the time between this date range's start, and the other date ranges start minus the buffer time
            long newRangeEnd = otherRange.getStartDate().getTime();
            this.setRangeEnd(new Date(newRangeEnd));
            return null;
        }

        // This will never happen, but the compiler doesn't know that
        System.out.println("This should never have happened. No comparisons between the date ranges was discovered");
        return null;



    }

    public static class DateRangeObliteratedException extends Exception {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5642891561498447972L;

        public DateRangeObliteratedException() {
            super("This date range no longer exists. It was entirely contained within the range you subtracted from it.");
        }
    }
}



                        for(int rangeIndex = 0; rangeIndex less than rangesBusy.size(); rangeIndex++) {
                            DateRange busyRange = rangesBusy.get(rangeIndex);
                            try {
                                DateRange trailingRange =  freeTimeBlock.subtract(busyRange, 0);

                                if(trailingRange != null) {
                                    freeTimeRanges.add(trailingRange);
                                }

                            } catch (DateRangeObliteratedException e) {
                                freeTimeRanges.remove(rangeIndex);
                                rangeIndex--;
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: thanks amarunowski for your answer. I think this is not what i want. I want to calculate total busy hours from the stored values. and i got it also. but i think problem is in my loop somewhere because if there is more than one records of a same date than it only taking last record's hours. I want to add all the hours.

Comment: So you want to know how many hours each day that the resource will be busy?

Comment: ya i want to know how many hours each day that the resource will be busy? how can i do that from SQL ?

Comment: Do you need the exact list of hours? Or do you just want a count of the number of hours it will be busy?

Comment: No i want the exact list of hours like 10,11,12,15,16

Comment: Except for being in java, the code I posted can do what you're attempting, and then some. If I had a much better specification for what your limitations are for input and output, I could just give you a query that would do the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you're expecting.  The key lines being those involving $all_finals and the moving of $final.  I usually write in python and didn't know the best way to append to an array in php so I used this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

```
$id = 6;    
$cdata = $test->getResourceEvents($id);

$h = "";
$all_finals = array();


foreach($cdata as $c)
   {
   $final= array();
   $sh = $c['starttime']->Format('H'); // Starting hour
   $eh = $c['endtime']->Format('H'); // End hour

   $hh = $sh;
   $final = array();
   $sdate = $c['starttime']->Format('Y-m-d');
   $edate = $c['endtime']->Format('Y-m-d');
   if($edate == $sdate)
   {

   $dh = $eh-$sh; // Duration
       for($i=1;$i<=$dh;$i++)
       {
           $hh = $hh.",".($sh+$i); // Busy hours
       }    
   $busyhrs[$sdate] = explode(",",$hh);
       $final[$sdate] = $busyhrs;
   }
   else
   {
       echo "false";
   }
   array_push($all_finals, $final);
}

print_r($all_final);
```

Comment: Sorry Jake. This all_final didnt work. I want to add hours to array if its a same date. Means i want to get total busy hours of a resource per day.